# How to insert a line break <br> after every <a> tag?

Tags: html, css

I want to insert a line break `<br>` after every `<a>` tag using CSS. I tried

```
a {
    display:inline;
}
a:after {
    content:"\a";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

but it does not work, I tested it in Chrome?

**My Question**

How to insert a line break `<br>` after every `<a>` using CSS?

Comment: Can you say at a higher level what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Could you not just make the anchor a block element?

Comment: What about making the `<a>` tag a block-level element?

Comment: @JamesKingsbery I have around 1000 hyperlink which I want to arrange I below another.

Comment: CSS is not designed for this.  It's meant for styling purposes, not markup changes.  I think you should find a better way of accomplishing what you're doing instead of a CSS hack.

Comment: Sounds like `display:block` would be the way to go if you can't control how the links are generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it a block level element, perhaps?

```
a { display: block; }
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/senoramor/ayRx7/).

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but the answer does not address the question asked (which might well not be the question that *should* have been asked). The proposed style sheet causes line break before and after an `a` element, not just after.

Comment: Technically, OP didn't ask for *just* after.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela the OP *did* specify that the links needed to be placed on a newline.  `display: block` does that.

Comment: Your suggested solution is causing the link to continue till the end of line beyond the text of the hyperlink. I think it does not work in the intended way also I believe it is not correct answer. Please air your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with CSS - that isn't what it was intended for.

You can use Javascript to do this.

Comment: It is obvious that it *can* be done with CSS (even the code in the question does that).

Comment: To insert the HTML element <br> - as is stated in the question??

Comment: the reference to `<br>` was meant to refer to a line break in rendering; the code in the question makes this clear.

Comment: Can you suggest a solution?

Answer (score -2):

That is obvious that you can not define content by using css. You can use simple Jquery `$("a").after("html here");`